# Autoloading phpunit test classes from another module in zf2

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-framework2

I am trying to reuse test classes from another module into my current module. My directory structure looks like:

```
Home/
    Module.php
    config/
        module.config.php
    src/
        Home/
            <code files>
    test/
        phpunit.xml
        bootstrap.php
        HomeTest/
            <test code files>
Loader/
    Module.php
    config/
        module.config.php
    src/
        Loader/
            <code files>
    test/
        phpunit.xml
        bootstrap.php
        LoaderTest/
            <test code files>
```

I am running phpunit test classes in Loader/test/ folder and need to reuse classes from Home/test/Hometest/Model.

I tried using this in my bootstrap file:

```
AutoloaderFactory::factory(
   array(
     'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
       'autoregister_zf' => true,
       'namespaces' => array(
         __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
        'HomeTest' => __DIR__ . '/Home/test/HomeTest',
       ),
     ),
   )
);
```

I am getting this error with the above loading mechanism:

```
Fatal error: Class 'HomeTest\Model\UserTableTest' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate back up the path from `Loader/test` to get to `Home/test`, try this...

```
AutoloaderFactory::factory(
    array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'autoregister_zf' => true,
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                'HomeTest' => __DIR__ . '/../../Home/test/HomeTest',
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```